# React App, Express Server - Set cookie not being stored in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, cookies, session-cookies

The long short is...

My express backend sets a cookie and sends it back to the client, **everything works great when I use Postman and my React Native app**. The issue is the web version which is done via ReactJs makes the same request but cookie is stored in the browser.

So I know cookies are working but not for the web version which is strange when I created a test endpoint `http://localhost:3000/server` and call it straight from the browser the cookie is stored.

So this is my code doing a simple fetch to the server which then sends back a cookie:

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://192.168.0.11:3000/server/`, {
        credentials: "include",
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        const resData = await res.json();
        console.log({ resData });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err });
    }
  };
```

The request came back successful but no cookie is stored

[image]

Access the same endpoint from the browser directly results in this:

[image]

[image]

An extract from the response header while being sent shows that the cookie was sent in the response just not stored in the frontend

[image]

Comment: What is the address serving the react app? I would be willing to bet that "express cors" is the topic you want to research. By default, cookies will only be stored if the react app and the server are being served from the same origin. If the url in the bar for your react app doesn't start with `http://192.168.0.11:3000`, then that's the issue.

Comment: @erich2k8 Why is it that the `react native` app works perfectly storing and serving the cookie? The `express cors` was set up as such `credentials: true, origin: true` the cookie was created and sent in the response header but somehow the `ReactJs` frontend does not recognize/see it.

Comment: react-native doesn't run in a browser. It doesn't even use cookies. There are libraries that approximate the behavior, but as e.g. `react-native-cookies` doesn't even have the word "origin" in the codebase, it clearly doesn't have the security measures that browsers do. Check the "blocked" tab in your screenshots above

Comment: Understood i used that library to handle the cookies. The blocked tabs are empty, there are not blocked cookies.

Comment: As stated before the cookie is being sent back to the client and when i type the endpoint directly into the browser it receives the cookie stores it and outputs the the JSON response as well. In the React app it just outputs the response and doesn't handle the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a pretty simple fix

I was using `http://localhost:3001` for the react app I just simply used the ip address instead `http://192.168.0.11:3001`

Comment: Where did you add it? I mean to say what exactly did you do to make it work?